# How to delete information from an old commit without 'erasing' my most recent commit

Tags: git

I have a file:

```
Crap + crap
Added R2 + crap
Added flags
Added MAE
```

with the following commit history:

```
* commit 385ea04 (HEAD, master)
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 03:56:26 2016 -0400
| 
|     Crap + crap
|  
* commit 9ba7feb
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:37:50 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added R2 + crap
|  
* commit 56a7ee2
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:36:14 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added flags.
|  
* commit 7189e56
  Author: av376
  Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:35:15 2016 -0400
```

The commit comments indicate what was added to the file.
What I want to do is modify my git commits so that I get the following git history sequence:

```
* commit 385ea04 (HEAD, master)
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 03:56:26 2016 -0400
| 
|     Crap + crap
|  
* commit 9ba7feb
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:37:50 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added R2
|  
* commit 56a7ee2
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:36:14 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added flags.
|  
* commit 7189e56
  Author: av376
  Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:35:15 2016 -0400
```

I have tried doing this with git rebase -i 9ba7feb^ (edit), but after resolving conflicts, I end up with:

```
* commit 9ba7feb
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:37:50 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added R2
|  
* commit 56a7ee2
| Author: av376
| Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:36:14 2016 -0400
| 
|     Added flags.
|  
* commit 7189e56
  Author: av376
  Date:   Thu Aug 4 02:35:15 2016 -0400
```

in which my most recent commit has disappeared.
Why does this happen?
Is it possible to do what I want?
If so, how?
I will appreciate answers with an excruciating amount of detail.

Comment: What command are you using in the last example when displaying the log?

Comment: you can do `git reset 56a7ee2` and then do git add -p to plan your commits as desired.

Comment: @1615903 `git log --graph --decorate --all --abbrev-commit`